# Possible for malware to set a BIOS password?

Tags: bios, passwords, malware

Strange issue.  My PC locked up and I reset it by holding down the power button.  It had been overclocked and I received a message that my PC had experienced a boot failure due to voltage issues.  I've gotten this before and I always just back off my overclock some.  This is an old i5-750 on a Gigabyte P55-UD4P.  However, this time when I went into BIOS setup to reconfigure the overclock it asked me for a password.  I've never set a BIOS password, and I live with my wife and two small children (5 and 2).  No one has been in my house to prank me by setting a password and I'm quite sure my wife and children couldn't figure it out either (even by accident) as this PC is NEVER turned off.  Luckily, it's just the setup password, I can still boot into Windows (running default clocks since it was reset due to the boot failure).

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?  I'm aware I can set the CMOS Clear jumper to reset it, but I'm still concerned as to how the password got there.

Comment: Is the password you have now a manufacturer backdoor password? They are listed here: http://www.techmixer.com/how-to-reset-bios-password-remove-bios-password-cmos-battery/ In this case it is possible has been set by overclocking?

Comment: In theory, yes. Malware could use bugs to get admin priveleges and then access hardware, including the firmware/EFI/BIOS/...  In practice ths would be very hard to do because you would have to write that for that specific motherboard. That way lies no profit, and hence little motivation for people to write such malware.